# problem when executing the function that connects me to the mongodb database

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to connect to mongodb and it does, but I have a problem, and that is that when I send a log to show me if the connection was successful, the message is executed twice, I do not know if that is normal or I have problems in the code, thanks for your help.

```
package connection

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/readpref"
)

// Client es la instancia de la conexion
var Client = Connection()

// Connection es la funcion que me permite conectarme a mongodb
func Connection() *mongo.Client {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))

    defer func() {
        if err = client.Disconnect(ctx); err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
    }()

    err = client.Ping(ctx, readpref.Primary())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    log.Println("conexion exitosa a mongodb")

    return client
}
```

this is my main file

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/HamelBarrer/api-go/connection"
)

func main() {
    connection.Connection()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing the connection before main() starts, so if you're also calling `Connection()` function after main() starts running, it will do it twice. However, your `Connection` function disconnects before returning from the function, which will, according to the documentation, disconnect from the database. It is not clear if reusing the client after a disconnect will reconnect. In any case, do not disconnect before returning the function.

Comment: It allows me to work with operation in the database but it keeps returning the two messages

Comment: Show the code where you use the connection. The documentation says `Disconnect` will close all connections to the DB, however it does not say whether those connections are restarted again when you use the client, so I might have misspoke there, I'll change my answer.

Comment: You are connecting twice. Once when the program starts, because you  declared `Client=Connection()`, and once when you call it in main.

Comment: And I answered, above: you are connecting twice. Check my comments.

Comment: If I already checked, thanks, I had not noticed, I was doing it twice

Answer (score 0):

```
package funtion

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/HamelBarrer/api-go/connection"
    "github.com/HamelBarrer/api-go/models"
)

// CreateUser es la funcion para crear en la bd
func CreateUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    collection := connection.Client.Database("testing").Collection("numbers")

    var user models.User

    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&user)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    insertResult, err := collection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), user)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(insertResult.InsertedID)
}
```